# How to avoid multiple for loops

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am new in JavaScript data structure. I am working on linked list in JavaScript. I want to create a function which can find the distance between nodes. I have created a function which work perfectly what i want. But i think this is not the way of writing time efficient code. Is there any way to replace those for loops in distance function to any other code that can give the same result with the time efficiency. Here is the distance function code.

```
linkList.prototype.distance = function (val1, val2) {
let node1 = this.search(val1);
let node2 = this.search(val2);
let info = {};
let node1Values = [...Object.keys(node1)];
let node2Values = [...Object.keys(node2)];
for (let i = 0; i < node1Values.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < node2Values.length; j++){
        info[`Distance From ${node1Values[i]} To ${node2Values[j]} is:`] = 
Math.abs(node1[node1Values[i]].Index - node2[node2Values[j]].Index);
    }
}
return info;    
};
```

Here is the search function code which is used by distance function.

```
linkList.prototype.search = function (value) {
let info = {};
let curNode = this.head;
let c = 0;
let duplicate = 1;
while (curNode) {
    if (curNode.value === value) {
        let info_arr = {};
        let val = curNode.value;
        let next = null;
        if (curNode.next) {
            next = curNode.next.value;
        }
        let prev = null;
        if (curNode.prev) {
            prev = curNode.prev.value;
        }
        let index = c;
        info_arr["Value"] = val;
        info_arr["Index"] = index;
        info_arr["Next"] = next;
        info_arr["Prev"] = prev;
        if (info[curNode.value]) {
            info[curNode.value + ":" + duplicate] = info_arr;
            duplicate++;
        } else {
            info[curNode.value] = info_arr;
        }

        }
        curNode = curNode.next;
        c++;
        }
        return info;
        };
```

[Here is the output of distance function when i console log it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJM52.png)

Comment: Can you describe the expected output? To be honest, I don't see much practical benefit of the output you generate now (with `Distance from 20`, `20:1`, `30:2`...): that will not be very handy for other code that should do something with that information.

Comment: @trincot expected output is calculating the distance from one node to another. If there is multiple node with same value i want to calculate each of the node distance individually.

Comment: I meant: what is the expected output format?

Comment: I am sorry that i have not mention the format earlier. Expected output format is:
"Distance from Node1.value To Node2.value is = distance(that is calculated)". this work is not professinal. Its only for learning how data structure works. thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: So my first comment applies. Anyway, you have working code it seems, so then your question is not really on-topic here. You could try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No its related though my function works i want to know if there is any way to avoid those for loops and get the same result in distance function. @trincot

Comment: Indeed, that is what I understood.